# Вывод текущего времени

Tags: javascript

Почему не работает код?

Сделано по примеру книги Д.В.Николенко "Практические занятия по JavaScript(4)"
стр.48-49

```
<body onLoad="clock()" >
<script language="javascript">
var TimeStr;

function clock() {
    now = new Date();
    H = now.getHours();
    M = now.getMinutes();
    S = now.getSeconds();

    TimeStr = "" + H;
    TimeStr += ((M < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + M;

    TimeStr += ((S < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + S;

    document.clock.time = TimeStr;

    Timer = setTimeout("clock()", 1000);
}
clock(); 
</script><form name="clock">
<input  type="text" size="8" value="" name="time" >
</form>
```

Comment: И что? В чем вопрос?

Comment: код не работоспособен.

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает что ошибка в строчке:

    document.clock.time = TimeStr;
    document.(тут список предлагаемых объектов и среди них нету clock. )

Comment: Вот это быдлокод О_О

Даже `var` нету, setTimeout в кавычках, меняйте книгу это ппц

Comment: так посоветуйте лучшую по вашему мнению)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неверное присвоение значения. Верно будет `document.clock.time.value=...`
Также `document.clock` не существует у Вас на момент первого вызова `clock()`, потому что сначала запускается скрипт, потом создается DOM-модель. Варианты решения проблемы:

1. Разместить скрипт после BODY
2. Убрать вызов clock() в последней строчке скипта

Comment: не один из предложенных вами вариантов не сработал.

Comment: Добавил...

Comment: приношу извинения..стоило внимательней просмотреть ваш пост..

Верно будет document.clock.time.value=...

все дело в этой строке..Огромноэ спасибо,избавили от унижений препода ;)

Comment: На самом деле я отредактировал ответ после Вашего комментария и потом написал в комментарии, что добавил :)

Comment: аа) я просто тогда подумал что вы добавили вопрос в "избранное"